# How to Get Response Data XML From Request API?

Tags: javascript, xml, api, axios

I use axios to make it. How to receive data in XML when I make an request API?

Example:

```
axios.get(/* URL */).then(response => {/* How to get data XML? */}).catch(err => {/* result */});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `.then` callback, the `response` has a property `data` it is the xml document as a string. Many people would use this string and parse it using a parser that is build into the browser, like it is demonstrated in this very recent question:
[Reading local text file as XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64680423/reading-local-text-file-as-xml)

I however would recomment using a parser library, these provide a much more effective way of working with xml data. My choice is [txml](https://npmjs.com/package/txml).
you can get it into your document like this:

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/txml@4.0.0/tXml.min.js"></script>
```

Then, when you parse the xml string like this:

```js
axios.get(/* URL */).then(response => {
   const dom = txml.parse(response.data);
}).catch(err => {/* result */});
```

The constant dom, is an array, of xml nodes. each node has the properties `tagName`, `attributes` and `children`. `children` is again an array of nodes.

the library has very handy helper functions like 'txml.simplify(dom)' will give you an object, that looks more like a data object. you can check the API documentation on [npm](https://npmjs.com/package/txml).

**DISCLAIMER:** I am the author of txml.